# Partial derivative of distribution function

Tags: calculus, economics

I'd recently read an article that said:

> Let $F(q|p)$ be the distribution function of demand, where $p$ is the retail price. It's natural to assume demand decreases stochastically in price, i.e., $\partial F(q|p)/ \partial p >0$.

So how can I understand why when $\partial F(q|p)/ \partial p >0$, the demand will decrease? What is the relationship between them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $F(q|p)$ is the cumulative distribution function, so it is monotonic increasing with range $[0,1]$.

This function says that when the price is $p$ we expect the quantity demanded to be a random variable $Q_p$ with cumulative distribution function $F_Q(q|p)$.

We say that random variable $X$ stochastically dominates random variable $Y$ if

$$P(X>z) \geq P(Y>z)\;\;\forall z$$
and

$$\exists z: P(X>z) > P(Y>z)$$

This is equivalent to $1-F_X(z) \geq 1-F_Y(z) \;\;\forall z$ and $\exists z: 1-F_X(z) > 1-F_Y(z)$

Going forward, we will assume $\exists z: P(X>z) > P(Y>z)$ to keep things easier to write.

---

Let $p,\delta>0$ and $p' = p+\delta$, then we expect that $1-F_Q(q|p) \geq 1-F_Q(q|p')$

Expressing this as the change in $F_Q$ we get:

$$1-F_Q(q|p) \geq 1-F(q|p') \implies F_Q(q|p) \leq F_Q(q|p') \implies 0\leq F_Q(q|p')-F_Q(q|p)$$

$$\implies 0 \leq \frac{F_Q(q|p')-F_Q(q|p)}{\delta} \;\;\forall q$$

Taking the limit as $\delta \to 0$ we get:

$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{F_Q(q|p')-F_Q(q|p)}{\delta} = \frac{\partial}{\partial p}F_Q(q|p)\geq 0 \;\;\;\forall q$$

If we assume that demand decreases for all quantities ordered as a function of price, then we can replace $\geq$ with $>$, as specified in your quote.